# 1 HTML form with 2 action buttons

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have read many posts regarding the various ways to have 2 action buttons on a single HTML form.  I chose to handle it using an if statement in the PHP function file to identify which button was clicked and run the appropriate code.  This is my first time using an IF statement and syntax seems to match the example.

```
<?php
//Connect to database
include("../ConfigFiles/ConnectDB_local_i.php");

 if($_POST["Calculate"])
 {
echo "<br>I clicked the Calculate button<br>";
 }

if(isset($_POST["Upload"]))
{
//Populating the variables
$InvoiceNo = $_POST["vInvoiceNo"];
$InvoiceDate = $_POST["vDate"];
$ClientName = $_POST["vName"];
$ClientAddress = $_POST["vAddress"];
$ClientPhone = $_POST["vPhone"];
$ClientEmail = $_POST["vEmail"];

$DescLine_1 = $_POST["vDescLine1"];

//Writting to DB
echo "<br>I wrote to the database<br>";
$query = "INSERT INTO `invoicedata_table` 
            (`InvoiceNo`, 
            `InvoiceDate`, 
            `ClientName`, 
            `ClientAddress`,  
            `ClientPhone`,  
            `ClientEmail`,

            `DescLine_1`) 
        VALUES 
            ('$InvoiceNo',
            '$InvoiceDate',
            '$ClientName',
            '$ClientAddress',
            '$ClientPhone',
            '$ClientEmail',

            '$DescLine_1');";
$mysqli->query($query) or die($query.'<br />'.$mysqli->error);
 }

//Close the DB connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I received the following error message:

Notice: Undefined index: Calculate in E:\EasyPHP\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\my portable files\AdminSecure\InvoiceSaveFunction.php on line 5

When reading more posts it seems this problem can be resolved by using isset().  When I tried (see second if), I don't get the error but it does not run the code either.

I suppose this will be simple to all you expects out there but I can't seem to figure it out.  I don't understand completely what I am doing.  I assume it must 
be about declaring variables or something similar?

This is the form code

```
<form action="InvoiceSaveFunction.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

Comment: Is your `form` set to `method="post"`?

Comment: Yes.  I updated info in my question above to add to form code.

Comment: Make sure your form method is set to "post" and your button's name is "Calculate"

Comment: I can't seem make the edit stick.  I'll try again.

Comment: The form code is there now.

Comment: You need to add the name attribute to your input buttons. Ex:  `name="Calculate"`

Comment: Adding the name attribute works.  Please put your comment as an answer so I can accept the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry praxmatig.  I meant the answer pertaining to name="Calculate" from j08691.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the name attribute to your input buttons.

Ex:

```
<input type="submit" name="Calculate" value="Calculate" />
<input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form method is set to "post" and your button's name is "Calculate"